# List.contains throwing null exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, join, lambda, contains

I have a join query like

```
 public ActionResult Import(int[] userValue, int[] provalue, DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate)
    {
        List<int> actallid = db.Activitys.Select(x=>x.ID).ToList();
        List<int> actchild = FileOperation.ChildActivity(actallid);

        DateTime Start_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate);
        DateTime End_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate);
        IEnumerable<ViewModelActivitySearch> search = from r in db.Reports
        join a in db.Activitys on r.ID equals a.Report_ID 
        join u in db.Users on r.Users_ID equals u.ID
        join p in db.Projects on a.Projects_ID equals p.ID
        join act in db.ActivityTypes on a.Activity_Type_ID equals act.ID
        where (
        (r.Start_Date == StartDate || r.End_Date == EndDate || userValue.Contains((int)r.Users_ID) || provalue.Contains((int)a.Projects_ID))
        &&
        //status is submitted=2, approved=3,exclude child activities
        (!actchild.Contains((int)a.ID)) 
         && 
        (r.Status == 2 || r.Status == 3)
         )
        select new ViewModelActivitySearch
        {
         Id = a.ID,
         Activity_Text = a.Activity_Text,
         Deliverable = a.Deliverable,
         Employee = string.Concat(u.FirstName, " ", u.LastName),
         Start_Date = r.Start_Date,
         End_Date = r.End_Date,
         Activity_Date = a.Activity_Date,
         Project = p.Name,
         category = act.Activity_Type
         };
        BindProjectAndUser();
        return View(search.ToList());
    }
```

I have a search page where the user can enter a start date,enddate,choose users and choose projects.
I then made a join query to fetch all the data according to that variables.
The problem is when the user doesnot choose any user or project 
the code

```
userValue.Contains((int)r.Users_ID) || provalue.Contains((int)a.Projects_ID))
```

gives the error

```
 Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Int32[]'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.
```

What else can I use instead of contains so that this error does not arises.
Thanks

Comment: Check first if the value is other than null? If(r.Users_ID != null)

Comment: I think your r.Users_ID or a.Projects_ID is null.

Comment: you cannot find a null in a list of int.

Comment: @deathismyfriend obvious..that's what he's saying..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for null in values that you try to cast explicitly to int (like r.Users_ID) with ternary operator before using Contains:

```
where (r.Start_Date == StartDate || r.End_Date == EndDate || 
r.Users_ID != null? userValue.Contains((int)r.Users_ID) : false || 
a.Projects_ID != null ?provalue.Contains((int)a.Projects_ID) : false)
```

Method Contains() is a method to check if there's a certain value in a list of values of same type and it's perfectly fine to use it here.

Answer (score 0):

**Always do server-side validation!**

Especially if you're using the users input for a SQL statement it's very important to validate it (*sql injection*)!

Simplest way: *if-statements*

```
if(userinput == null){
   return View();
}
```

*Note: If you are using `Convert.ToDateTime()`, you won't get an exception if the provided DateTime is **null**. You'll get the **DateTime.MinValue** and this could end in unexpected results.*

Comment: Thanks .Is there any other way? I don't wanna use "userValue.Contains((int)r.Users_ID)" Is there any other way other than contains

Comment: @smriti You want to check if a specific id is inside the int-array?

Comment: I want to check all the id that are comman in uservalue and r.Users_ID